# Does Scalaz have something to accumulate in both error and success?

Tags: scala, monads, fold, scalaz, applicative

I started to use Scalaz 7 Validation and/or disjunction to process a list of possibly failing operation and managing their result.

There is two well documented case for that kind of use cases:

1/ You want to check a list of conditions on something, and accumulate each error if any. Here, you always go the end of list, and in case of any error, you have failure as global result. 
And that's an applicative functor at work.

2/ You want to execute several steps that may fail, and stop on the first one failing. 
Here, we have a monad that goes nicely in Scala for-comprehension.

So, I have two other use cases  that are among the same lines, but don't seems to feet well on any precedent case:
I want to process a list of step, possibly failing, and accumulate both error and success results (ex: it's a list of modification on files, errors may happen because that's the outer world, and success are patch that I want to keep for later).

The difference on the two use case is only if I want to stop early (on the first error) or go to the end of the list.

OK, so what is the correct thing for that ?

(writting the question leads me to think that it's just a simple foldLeft, does it ? I will let the question here to validate, and if anybody else wonder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
scala> List(1.success[String], 2.success[String], "3".failure[Int], "4".failure[Int]).partition(_.isSuccess)
res2: (List[scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int]], List[scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int]]) = (List(Success(1), Success(2)),List(Failure(3), Failure(4)))

scala> val fun = (_:List[Validation[String, Int]]).reduceLeft(_ append _)
fun: List[scalaz.Validation[String,Int]] => scalaz.Validation[String,Int] = <function1>

scala> fun <-: res2 :-> fun
res3: (scalaz.Validation[String,Int], scalaz.Validation[String,Int]) = (Success(3),Failure(34))
```

**UPD:** With [#129](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/129) and [#130](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/130) merged, you can change `fun` to `(_:List[Validation[String, Int]]).concatenate` or `(_:List[Validation[String, Int]]).suml`

Or `bimap` like this:

```
scala> List(1.success[String], 2.success[String], "3".failure[Int], "4".failure[Int]).partition(_.isSuccess).bimap(_.suml, _.suml)
res6: (scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int], scalaz.Validation[java.lang.String,Int]) = (Success(3),Failure(34))
```

Comment: Note that this uses the default monoid for Validation, which delegates to +++ for appending. +++ returns the first failure, not the appended failure.  E.g.: scala> List(1.failure[String], 2.failure[String]).reduceLeft { _ |+| _ }
res0: scalaz.Validation[Int,String] = Failure(1)

Comment: @mpilquist Well, this behavior has changed recently: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/114. Updated my answer to be more precise about this.

Comment: Hmm take a look at Tony's disjunction merge.  It appears that the change in pull 114 was lost.  The code I ran above is from a local build of scalaz-seven that's up to date.

Comment: Now that's confusing. I was so sure, because I was actually changing that instance. Updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I bet it was accidental.  I'd mention it to Tony and see what he thinks.

Comment: If the default goes back to the change from pull 114, then l.concatenate would work too.

Comment: I've created another pull request to restore it: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/pull/129.

Comment: See also [_Validation_](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html) from [_Learning Scalaz_](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz), and [a similar answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/700420) for more help and usage with `NonEmptyList`.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `Validation#append` or its alias `Validation#+|+`.  Given two validations, if both are success, it returns success of the values appended.  If both are failures, it returns failure of the values appended.  Otherwise, it returns the successful value.  This requires an implicit Semigroup instance for the success type.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is approximately switching an `Either[E, A]` into a `Writer[List[E], A]`. The `Writer` monad logs the errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a pair `(SomveValue, List[T])` where `T` is your 'Failure' although I'd call it 'Warning' or 'Log' since you still get a result, so its not really a failure.

Don't know if Scalaz has anything fancy for this though.

Comment: (W, A) is the Writer[A] monad, W usually being a semigroup (able to accumulate).