# scala: idiomatic and functional way to add errors to a list of errors

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have the following validation method:

```
def validate(wine: Wine): List[Error] = {

  var errors = List[Error]()

  if (Validate.isEmptyWord(wine.name)) {
    errors ::= ValidationError("name", "Name not specified")
  } else {
    if (isDuplicate(wine, "name")) {
      errors ::= ValidationError("name", "There already exists a wine with the name '%s'".format(wine.name))
    }
  }

  if (Validate.isEmptyWord(wine.grapes)) {
    errors ::= ValidationError("grapes", "Grapes not specified")
  }

  if (Validate.isEmptyWord(wine.country)) {
    errors ::= ValidationError("country", "Country not specified")
  }

  // more stuff like this and finnally
  errors.reverse
}
```

You get the idea

How would you modify it to avoid the var List[Error] and make it more functional?

Answer (score 10):

[Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) provides a `Validation` class that makes a functional approach to this kind of problem very easy. There's a more detailed example of how to use `Validation` in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519), but I'll also give a sketch here to show how it might work in your situation. I'll assume the following setup:

```
case class Wine(name: String, grapes: String, country: String)
case class ValidationError(name: String, msg: String)
```

Now we can write a couple of validation methods (note that I'm using Scalaz 7):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def checkNonempty(v: String, name: String, msg: String) =
  if (v.nonEmpty) v.successNel else ValidationError(name, msg).failNel

def checkDuplicate(v: String, name: String, msg: String) =
  if (true) v.successNel else ValidationError(name, msg).failNel
```

Where of course you should add your own duplication checking to the last line. Then we can wrap it all together:

```
def createWine(name: String, grape: String, country: String) = (
  checkNonempty(name, "name", "Name not specified").flatMap(_ =>
    checkDuplicate(name, "name",
      "There already exists a wine with the name '%s'".format(name)
    )
  ) |@|
  checkNonempty(grape, "grape", "Grape not specified") |@|
  checkNonempty(country, "country", "Country not specified")
)(Wine.apply)
```

Now if we write something like this:

```
val result: ValidationNEL[ValidationError, Wine] = createWine(
  "Whatever Estates", "Whatever Grape", "U.S."
)
```

We'll get a success value:

```
Success(Wine(Whatever Estates,Whatever Grape,U.S.))
```

But if we give it invalid input:

```
val result: ValidationNEL[ValidationError, Wine] = createWine(
  "", "Some Grape", ""
)
```

We'll get a list of the accumulated errors:

```
Failure(
  NonEmptyList(
    ValidationError(name,Name not specified),
    ValidationError(country,Country not specified)
  )
)
```

You could also roll your own validation logic, of course, but using a library like Scalaz is probably worth the trouble if you're doing much of this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Write your `isX` methods to return an `Option[Error]` instead of a `Boolean`, and then

```
List(
  Validate.isEmptyWord(wine.name, "name", "Name not specified").
  orElse( Validate.isDuplicate(wine.name, "name", "There already exists...") ),
  Validate.isEmptyWord(wine.grapes, "grapes", "Grapes not specified"),
  ...
).flatten
```

and you'll have your errors.  Also, there's plenty of other duplication you could remove (e.g. if it's always `"x", "X not specified"`, you can just supply `"x"` and have the rest filled in by `isEmptyWord`).

Comment: sure, I'm just starting to optimize the whole thing, thanks for the tip

Comment: If you don't need anything in the success case besides just a boolean then this is a good route to go.  The scalaz route is good when you need to create an object out of the pieces in the success case.