# Can a function return one of multiple types which do not share a common ancestor?

Tags: scala

Of course I realize all types *do* have a common ancestor, but what I mean is this:

In dynamically-typed languages, it is a common practice to have 'mixed' return types. A common case is a function which attempts to retrieve data from a database, then returns either an object (initialized with the found data) or FALSE (in the event no data was found).

A little pseudocode to demonstrate just such an anti-pattern:

```
function getObjectFromDatabase(object_id) {
  if(result = db_fetch_object("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = %d", object_id) {
    return result
  } else {
    return FALSE
  }
}
```

If data is found for my object id, I get a DB record back as an object. If not, I get a boolean value. Then, of course, it is on me, the client, to handle multiple possible return types.

Is the only way to accomplish this in Scala to find a common ancestor for all possible return types and declare that as the return type in the signature?

```
// Like so:
def getObjectFromDatabase(objectId: Int): Any = {
   val result = dbFetchObject("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = %d", object_id) 
   if(result) {
     return result
   } else {
     return false
  }
}
```

Or is it possible to annotate multiple possible return types?

(Note that I do not *hope* it is possible to do this, as I would prefer it to be enforced that function return types are as unambiguous as possible. It would come as a relief to me to learn that the language forbids ambiguous return types, which is more the reason I am asking.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *tagged union*, *variant*, *variant record*, *discriminated union*, *disjoint union*, or *sum type*.

Combined with *product types*, they become *algebraic datatypes*.

Scala does not have direct support for algebraic datatypes, but it doesn't need to, because they can be easily modeled by inheritance. (Scala *does* have the `sealed` modifier to support *closed* ADTs.)

**NOTE: As of Scala 3, Scala *does* support algebraic sum types directly, in the form of [`enum`s](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/enums/adts.html). All of the below only applies to Scala 2.**

In your example, if you know that the return type is either `SomeType` or `SomeOtherType`, you can model it like this:

```
sealed trait ReturnType

final case class SomeType extends ReturnType
final case class SomeOtherType extends ReturnType

def meth: ReturnType
```

If you don't know what the return types are, only that there are two of them, then you can model it similarly:

```
sealed trait ReturnType[A, B]

final case class Type1[A, B](a: A) extends ReturnType[A, B]
final case class Type2[A, B](b: B) extends ReturnType[A, B]

def meth: ReturnType[A, B]
```

This is actually a well-known datatype called an `Either` (because it holds either an `A` or a `B`), and is present in Scala's standard library as `scala.util.Either`.

But in your specific case, there is a more specific type, called `Maybe` or `Option`, which encapsulates the idea that a value maybe exists or maybe not. It looks something like this:

```
sealed trait Maybe[T]

case object None extends Maybe[Nothing]
final case class Just[T](value: T) extends Maybe[T]

def meth: Maybe[T]
```

Again, this is already provided by Scala as `scala.Option`.

The advantage of `Either` over `Option` is that it allows you to also return information in the failure case instead of only indicating that there is no value you can also say *why* there is no value. (By convention, the left side of the `Either` is the error, the right side is the "useful" value.)

The advantage of `Option` is that it is a monad. (Note: you can make `Either` a monad by biasing it either to the left or the right.)

Comment: What if `SomeType` and `SomeOtherType` (your first example) have different fields,  each of which might be used differently by the caller of `meth` depending on the return value?  i.e. say I want to do something like `if (condition) retVal.fieldA else (retVal.fieldB + retVal.fieldB` (where `retVal` is the return of the `meth` method?

Answer (score 22):

Yes, use [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Either.html):

```
def getObjectFromDatabase(objectId: Int): Either[Boolean, DbResult] = {
   val result = dbFetchObject("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = %d", object_id) 
   if (result) Right(result) else Left(false)

}

getObjectFromDatabase(id) match {
  case Right(result) => // do something with result
  case Left(bool) => // do something with bool
}
```

Or, if the no results case doesn't need a specific value, use [`Option`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html):

```
def getObjectFromDatabase(objectId: Int): Option[DbResult] = {
   val result = dbFetchObject("SELECT * FROM objects WHERE id = %d", object_id) 
   if (result) Some(result) else None
}

getObjectFromDatabase(id) match {
  case Some(result) => // do something with result
  case None => // do something about no results
}
```

See Tony Morris' [Option Cheat Sheet](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/index.html) for a list of the most common methods you can call on `Option` and how they translate to pattern matching.

Two other alternatives are [`Validation`](http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc/scalaz/Validation.html) from scalaz and [`Try`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Try.html), new in Scala 2.10.

For `Validation` there are some really good answers on StackOverflow, for example: [Method parameters validation in Scala, with for comprehension and monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307965/method-parameters-validation-in-scala-with-for-comprehension-and-monads/12309023#12309023).

For `Try` see this blog post: [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 6: Error Handling With Try](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/26/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try.html).  The same author has good posts on [`Option`](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html) and [`Either`](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/02/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-7-the-either-type.html).

Comment: `Either` is a valid choice only if the intended return type can logically be only one of the 2 types. It is not a good logical solution if conceptually you can later add another type. i.e. there is no such thing as `Either[Int, String, Double]`

Answer (score 2):

If you will you know at runtime what type you are querying for in each call, your signature could be as:

```
def getObjectFromDatabase[T](object_id: Int): T = {
```

Or, to simulate your if/else logic there, I would recommend using Option here:

```
def getObjectFromDatabase[T](object_id: Int): Option[T] = {
  ...
  if(result) Some(result)
  else None
}
```

Example usage:

```
val result = getObjectFromDatabase[String](123123).getOrElse(whatever_you_need)
```