# Validating Json with Reads[T] in Play Framework

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Looking at a simple Scala Play JSON example (from the Play [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonCombinators)) to validate JSON (type `JsValue`) against a `case class`:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

scala> implicit val creatureReads: Reads[Creature] = (
     |  (__ \ "name").read[String] and
     |  (__ \ "isDead").read[Boolean])
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.Reads]
#CanBuild2[String,Boolean]
 required: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Creature]
        (__ \ "name").read[String] and
                                   ^
```

Then, eventually call this:

```
scala> val creature = Json.obj(  "name" -> "zombie", "isDead" -> true )
creature: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"name":"zombie","isDead":true}

scala> creature.validate[Creature]
...
```

But, how can I resolve the `type mismatch` I'm seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there—all you need to do is apply your `CanBuild2` to the `Creature` constructor:

```
implicit val creatureReads: Reads[Creature] = (
  (__ \ "name").read[String] and (__ \ "isDead").read[Boolean]
)(Creature)
```

And everything will work as expected. This syntax is a little convoluted, but you can think of it as "lifting" the constructor into the applicative functor for `Reads`, which allows you to apply it to the two `Reads` values for the fields. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712923/334519) refers to Scalaz's applicative builder syntax instead of Play's, but they're essentially the same—just read `|@|` as `and`:

> One part of the weirdness is that `xs |@| ys` doesn't really mean
>   anything on its own—it's essentially an argument list that's waiting
>   to be applied to a function that it will lift into its applicative
>   functor and apply to itself.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519) and blog post [here](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/) for additional discussion.

Comment: Just read your first linked answer. Clear and informative - thanks.