# When and why should one use Applicative Functors in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, applicative

I know that `Monad` can be expressed in Scala as follows:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def flatMap[A, B](f: A => F[B]): F[A] => F[B]
}
```

I see why it is useful. For example, given two functions:

```
getUserById(userId: Int): Option[User] = ...
getPhone(user: User): Option[Phone] = ...
```

I can easily write function `getPhoneByUserId(userId: Int)` since `Option` is a monad:

```
def getPhoneByUserId(userId: Int): Option[Phone] = 
  getUserById(userId).flatMap(user => getPhone(user))
```

...

Now I see `Applicative Functor` in Scala:

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] {
  def apply[A, B](f: F[A => B]): F[A] => F[B]
}
```

I wonder when I should use it *instead of* monad . I guess both Option and List are `Applicatives`. Could you give simple examples of using `apply` with Option and List and explain *why* I should use it *instead of* `flatMap` ?

Comment: Check "scalaz" [example](http://www.casualmiracles.com/2012/01/16/a-small-example-of-applicative-functors-with-scalaz/), [tutorial example](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Applicative.html), [scalaz tutorial](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/)

Comment: monad is not only a trait with a `flatMap` method but also a `unit` method and also some laws that must be verified.

Comment: @YannMoisan That's correct. I omitted them for simplicity.

Comment: @GabrielRiba I checked the scalaz example. I see how they use `<*>` but I still don't understand _why_ the example with `<*>` is better than the examples without it. All the examples seem to solve the problem.

Comment: it seems that scalaz (<*>) takes the lifted function on the right hand side, (reverse from Haskell) but (<*>) is left associative (right associative ops end in ':'), so you need to right parenthesize all (<*>) terms.
The alternate syntax with (|@|) is cleaner.

Comment: This is a very useful set of examples and questions. I had a question about the first example, though. Shouldn't the return type of flatMap be F[B], rather than a function, F[A] =>F[B]? For an example of flatMap returning F[B] see D. Wampler, Programming in Scala, p. 417. In other words, in your example, getPhoneByUserId() will return an Option[Phone], not a function Option[User]=>Option[Phone].

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To [quote myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519):

> So why bother with applicative functors at all, when we've got monads?
>   First of all, it's simply not possible to provide monad instances for
>   some of the abstractions we want to work with—`Validation` is the
>   perfect example.
>
> Second (and relatedly), it's just a solid development practice to use
>   the least powerful abstraction that will get the job done. In
>   principle this may allow optimizations that wouldn't otherwise be
>   possible, but more importantly it makes the code we write more
>   reusable.

To expand a bit on the first paragraph: sometimes you don't have a choice between monadic and applicative code. See the rest of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519) for a discussion of why you might want to use Scalaz's `Validation` (which doesn't and can't have a monad instance) to model
validation.

About the optimization point: it'll probably be a while before this is generally relevant in Scala or Scalaz, but see for example [the documentation for Haskell's `Data.Binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.7.1.0/docs/Data-Binary-Get.html):

> The applicative style can sometimes result in faster code, as `binary`
>   will try to optimize the code by grouping the reads together.

Writing applicative code allows you to avoid making unnecessary claims about dependencies between computations—claims that similar monadic code would commit you to. A sufficiently smart library or compiler *could* in principle take advantage of this fact.

To make this idea a little more concrete, consider the following monadic code:

```
case class Foo(s: Symbol, n: Int)

val maybeFoo = for {
  s <- maybeComputeS(whatever)
  n <- maybeComputeN(whatever)
} yield Foo(s, n)
```

The `for`-comprehension desugars to something more or less like the following:

```
val maybeFoo = maybeComputeS(whatever).flatMap(
  s => maybeComputeN(whatever).map(n => Foo(s, n))
)
```

We know that `maybeComputeN(whatever)` doesn't depend on `s` (assuming these are well-behaved methods that aren't changing some mutable state behind the scenes), but the compiler doesn't—from its perspective it needs to know `s` before it can start computing `n`.

The applicative version (using Scalaz) looks like this:

```
val maybeFoo = (maybeComputeS(whatever) |@| maybeComputeN(whatever))(Foo(_, _))
```

Here we're explicitly stating that there's no dependency between the two computations.

(And yes, this `|@|` syntax is pretty horrible—see [this blog post](http://meta.plasm.us/posts/2013/06/05/applicative-validation-syntax/) for some discussion and alternatives.)

The last point is really the most important, though. Picking the *least* powerful tool that will solve your problem is a tremendously powerful principle. Sometimes you really do need monadic composition—in your `getPhoneByUserId` method, for example—but often you don't.

It's a shame that both Haskell and Scala currently make working with monads so much more convenient (syntactically, etc.) than working with applicative functors, but this is mostly a matter of historical accident, and developments like [*idiom brackets*](https://github.com/aztek/scala-workflow/) are a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 30):

Functor is for lifting computations to a category.

```
trait Functor[C[_]] {
  def map[A, B](f : A => B): C[A] => C[B]
}
```

And it works perfectly for a function of one variable.

```
val f = (x : Int) => x + 1
```

But for a function of 2 and more, after lifting to a category, we have the following signature:

```
val g = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x + y
Option(5) map g // Option[Int => Int]
```

And it is the signature of a applicative functor. And to apply the following  value to a function `g` — an aplicative functor is needed.

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] {
  def apply[A, B](f: F[A => B]): F[A] => F[B]
}
```

And finally:

```
(Applicative[Option] apply (Functor[Option] map g)(Option(5)))(Option(10))
```

Applicative functor is a functor for applying a special value (value in category) to a lifted function.