# How to 'reach into an Option[String]' and make the string lower case?

Tags: scala

I have an Option[String] and I want to make sure that the string is lower case. What is the idiomatic way to 'reach into' the Option and make the transformation without having to extract the string and then put it back into an Option?

Thanks

Comment: You can `map`, there are a lot of examples around about mapping options.

Comment: I don't know why they called it `map` instead of `reachInto`.

Comment: so what is wrong with my question that warrants people to down vote it? Sorry we are not all born geniuses.

Comment: I agree. I think people forget that they didn't always know this stuff. You'll definitely want to do some research. FYI, `Option` is an *applicative functor*, which is basically a fancy way of saying it has a `map` method that modify the data it contains, even converting it to a different type.

Comment: @acjay That's just a functor, without the "applicative" part.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov For my own enlightenment and others', could you explain the difference?

Comment: @acjay See e.g. http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Applicative.html or http://stackoverflow.com/a/19882450/9204.

Answer (score 6):

Just call `map` on it:

```
stringOpt.map(_.toLowerCase)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
val x : Option[String] = Some("Hello")
x map (_.toLowerCase)
res2: Option[String] = Some(hello)
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, however that takes all letters to lowercase and I need the first letter in the sentence to remain Upper case...

Comment: Look for an additional method inside of the StringOps library which is here http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps