# Concurrent for-comprehensions

Tags: scala, akka

According to this [blog post](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html) there's a potential performance issue with for comprehensions. For example:

```
for {
  a <- remoteCallA()
  b <- remoteCallB()
} yield {
  (a, b)
}
```

has `remoteCallB` blocked until `remoteCallA` is completed.  The blog post suggests that we do this instead:

```
futureA <- remoteCallA()
futureB <- remoteCallB()
for {
  a <- futureA
  b <- futureB
} yield {
  (a, b)
}
```

which will ensure that the two remote calls can start at the same time.

My question: is the above (and therefore the blog writer) correct?

I've not seen people using this pattern, which has got me wondering whether there are alternative patterns that are generally used instead.

With thanks

Comment: As a side note, I don't think "performance issue" is exactly correct, I'd rather say that there's a difference between what was expressed and what was intended. The code, as written, says "do A then B then combine the results", the intent is to say "do A AND B then combine the results"

Comment: Thanks for your input, appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common pattern to execute several futures simultaneously is to use `zip` or `Future.traverse`. Here are a few examples:

```
for {
  (a, b) <- remoteCallA() zip remoteCallB()
} yield f(a, b)
```

This becomes a bit cumbersome when there are more than 2 futures:

```
for {
  ((a, b), c) <- remoteCall() zip remoteCallB() zip remoteCallC()
} yield (a, b, c)
```

In those cases you can use `Future.sequence`:

```
for {
  Seq(a, b, c) <- 
    Future.sequence(Seq(remoteCallA(), remoteCallB(), remoteCallC()))
} yield (a, b, c)
```

or `Future.traverse`, in case you have a sequence of arguments, and want to apply  to all of them the same function, which returns a `Future`.

But both approaches have an issue: if one of the `Future`s fails early, before the others finish, naturally you may want the resulting `Future` to fail immediately at that moment. But that's not what happens. The result `Future` is failed only after all the futures have completed. See this question for details: [How to implement Future as Applicative in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983542/how-to-implement-future-as-applicative-in-scala/29986065#29986065)

Answer (score 4):

The for comprehension

```
for {
  a <- remoteCallA()
  b <- remoteCallB()
} yield {
  (a, b)
}
```

Translates to:

```
remoteCallA().flatmap(a => remoteCallB().map(b => (a,b)))
```

So, yes, I believe the blogger is correct in that the calls will be sequential, not concurrent, to one another.

Comment: This is why people ask for `for (fa = A(); fb = B(); a <- fa` etc. There's also `Future.fold` and friends, when it applies.

Comment: Not sure that there really are any other than the one suggested by the blogger. I know that the Scalaz task provides a greater level of control over when things are executed vs. when they are specified, but the nature of a for comprehension is to use flatmap, and flapmap sort of implies dependency.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use = inside a for that way, thanks som-snytt

Comment: You can't, but people ask for the feature. It's a convenience, with better scoping.

Comment: I just came across the ticket. It's an ancient desire. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-907