# Applicative functors vs monad composing performance in Scala

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I have two monad instances `val a: M[A]` and `val b: M[B]`. Would there be any performance difference in the following code cases?

```
def f: (A, B) => C

val applicativeCombine = (a |@| b)(f)

val monadCombine = 
  for {
   aa <- a
   bb <- b
  } yield f(aa, bb)
```

... or does it depend?

Comment: You should probably add a `scalaz` tag, since it's not clear from the question itself where the `|@|` is coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are methods that return futures and perform some computationally expensive operation, the `applicativeCombine` version will run them in parallel while `monadCombine` won't, which means `|@|` could be close to twice as fast.

If `a` and `b` are options, on the other hand—or even futures that aren't doing computationally expensive work—it's possible that the `for` version may be faster, since its desugared form involves a couple fewer allocations:

```
scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> showCode(reify((Option(1) |@| Option(2))(_ + _)).tree)
res0: String = Scalaz.ToApplyOps(Option.apply(1))(Scalaz.optionInstance).|@|(Option.apply(2)).apply(((x$1, x$2) => x$1.+(x$2)))(Scalaz.optionInstance)

scala> showCode(reify(for { a <- Option(1); b <- Option(2) } yield a + b).tree)
res1: String = Option.apply(1).flatMap(((a) => Option.apply(2).map(((b) => a.+(b)))))
```

(But this is unlikely to make a meaningful difference in most programs.)

If this is Cats and the `a` and `b` are eithers and you have the "wrong" imports, so that you're getting `FlatMapSyntax` and `EitherInstances` instead of `EitherSyntax`, the `|@|` version might again be faster, since the `for` version would result in at least a couple of extra `Unapply` instances and some other stuff.

So the short answer is yes, it depends, and if you're really concerned about performance you'll need to do careful benchmarking for your particular use case.

The best reason to prefer the applicative version doesn't have anything to do with performance, though—it's that it's a more precise representation of the computation you want to perform. Your `a` and `b` don't depend on each other, but the `for`-comprehension says they do. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19881777/334519) for more discussion.