# Errors accumulation with Monoid

Tags: scala, concurrency, monoids, scala-cats

Suppose I have a list of functions `E => Either[Exception, Unit]` to invoke upon event `E` and accumulate the errors to return `Either[List[Exception], Unit]`.

```
type EventHandler = E => Either[Exception, Unit]

import cats.data.NonEmptyList

def fire(
  e: Event, 
  subscribers: List[EventHandler]
): Either[NonEmptyList[Exception], Unit] = ???
```

I'd like to implement `fire` with `cats`

```
 import cats.implicits._

 subscribers.foldMap (_ map (_.toValidatedNel))
            .map (.toEither)
            .apply(e)
```

Does it make sense ? How would you improve it ?
How to change `fire` to invoke `subscribers` concurrently ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably write it like this:

```
import cats.data.NonEmptyList, cats.implicits._

type Event = String    
type EventHandler = Event => Either[Exception, Unit]

def fire(
  e: Event,
  subscribers: List[EventHandler]
): Either[NonEmptyList[Exception], Unit] =
  subscribers.traverse_(_(e).toValidatedNel).toEither
```

(If you're not on 2.12.1 or are but can't use `-Ypartial-unification` you'll need `traverseU_`.)

If you want the calls to happen concurrently, normally you'd reach for `EitherT[Future, Exception, _]`, but that's not going to give you the error accumulation you want. There's no `ValidatedT`, but that's because `Applicative` composes directly. So you could do something like this:

```
import cats.Applicative
import cats.data.{ NonEmptyList, ValidatedNel }, cats.implicits._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

type Event = String
type EventHandler = Event => Future[Either[Exception, Unit]]

def fire(
  e: Event,
  subscribers: List[EventHandler]
): Future[Either[NonEmptyList[Exception], Unit]] =
  Applicative[Future].compose[ValidatedNel[Exception, ?]].traverse(subscribers)(
    _(e).map(_.toValidatedNel)
  ).map(_.void.toEither)
```

(Note that if you're not using kind-projector you'll need to write out the type lambda instead of using `?`.)

And to prove to yourself that it's happening concurrently:

```
fire(
  "a",
  List(
    s => Future { println(s"First: $s"); ().asRight },
    s => Future { Thread.sleep(5000); println(s"Second: $s"); ().asRight },
    s => Future { println(s"Third: $s"); ().asRight }
  )
)
```

You'll see `First` and `Third` immediately.

Comment: Thank you ! Why would you write with `Applicative` rather than `Monoid`. I guess `Applicative` is more generic and probably "more idiomatic" but `Monoid` seems simpler to me. Besides `Validated` has a `Monoid` instance after all. It has it for a reason.

Comment: @Michael It's a matter of taste, but "perform this operation on all these elements" feels more traverse-y to me.

Comment: Isn't monoid the "least powerful abstraction" for this case, as it's explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19881777/521070 ?