# How to accumulate errors in Either?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, either

Suppose I have few case classes and functions to test them:

```
case class PersonName(...)
case class Address(...)
case class Phone(...)

def testPersonName(pn: PersonName): Either[String, PersonName] = ...
def testAddress(a: Address): Either[String, Address] = ...
def testPhone(p: Phone): Either[String, Phone] = ...
```

Now I define a new case class `Person` and a test function, which *fails fast*.

```
case class Person(name: PersonName, address: Address, phone: Phone)

def testPerson(person: Person): Either[String, Person] = for {
  pn <- testPersonName(person.name).right
  a <- testAddress(person.address).right
  p <- testPhone(person.phone).right
} yield person;
```

Now I would like function `testPerson` to *accumulate* the errors rather than just fail fast.

I would like `testPerson` to always execute all those `test*` functions and return `Either[List[String], Person]`. How  can I do that ?

Comment: I know this isn't what you want to hear, but error accumulation and `for`-comprehensions (or any kind of monadic sequencing) just don't mix. For example, what if you'd used `pn` in the call to `testAddress` and `testPersonName` fails?

Comment: Take a look at `ValidationNel` from [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz). See [Learning scalaz/Validation](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html).  In your case: `def tesPersonName(pn: PersonName): ValidationNel[String, PersonName] = ...` => `(testPersonName(person.name) |@| testAddress(person.address) |@| testPhone(person.phone))(Person)`.

Comment: You could also take a look at [this library](https://github.com/youdevise/eithervalidation). It allows you to combine `Either` in the way you want: `Right(Person)(testPersonName(person.name), testAddress(person.address), testPhone(person.phone))`. Disclaimer: I didn't try this library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scala's `for`-comprehensions (which desugar to a combination of calls to `flatMap` and `map`) are designed to allow you to sequence monadic computations in such a way that you have access to the result of earlier computations in subsequent steps. Consider the following:

```
def parseInt(s: String) = try Right(s.toInt) catch {
  case _: Throwable => Left("Not an integer!")
}

def checkNonzero(i: Int) = if (i == 0) Left("Zero!") else Right(i)

def inverse(s: String): Either[String, Double] = for {
  i <- parseInt(s).right
  v <- checkNonzero(i).right
} yield 1.0 / v
```

This won't accumulate errors, and in fact there's no reasonable way that it could. Suppose we call `inverse("foo")`. Then `parseInt` will obviously fail, which means there's no way we can have a value for `i`, which means there's no way we could move on to the `checkNonzero(i)` step in the sequence.

In your case your computations don't have this kind of dependency, but the abstraction you're using (monadic sequencing) doesn't know that. What you want is an `Either`-like type that isn't monadic, but that is *applicative*. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12309023/334519) for some details about the difference.

For example, you could write the following with [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s `Validation` without changing any of your individual validation methods:

```
import scalaz._, syntax.apply._, syntax.std.either._

def testPerson(person: Person): Either[List[String], Person] = (
  testPersonName(person.name).validation.toValidationNel |@|
  testAddress(person.address).validation.toValidationNel |@|
  testPhone(person.phone).validation.toValidationNel
)(Person).leftMap(_.list).toEither
```

Although of course this is more verbose than necessary and is throwing away some information, and using `Validation` throughout would be a little cleaner.

Comment: `<console>:31: error: value validation is not a member of Either[String,Int]` what should I import? `myEither.disjunction.validation.toValidationNel` works fine.

Comment: Oh, right—`.validation` on `Either` is [new in `7.1`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/std/EitherOps.scala). So yeah, going through a disjunction or using `Validation.fromEither` is your best bet in 7.0.

Comment: As far as I remember, you should avoid catching `Throwable` in Scala. So `parseInt` should catch `Exception`: `case _: Exception => ...`.

Comment: @r0estir0bbe Really it should be `case NonFatal(e) =>`, but I don't think it's terribly relevant to the topic.

Answer (score 17):

You want to isolate the `test*` methods and stop using a comprehension!

Assuming (for whatever reason) that scalaz isn't an option for you... it can be done without having to add the dependency.

Unlike a lot of scalaz examples, this is one where the library doesn't reduce verbosity much more than "regular" scala can:

```
def testPerson(person: Person): Either[List[String], Person] = {
  val name  = testPersonName(person.name)
  val addr  = testAddress(person.address)
  val phone = testPhone(person.phone)

  val errors = List(name, addr, phone) collect { case Left(err) => err }

  if(errors.isEmpty) Right(person) else Left(errors)      
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As @TravisBrown is telling you, for comprehensions don't really mix with error accumulations. In fact, you generally use them when you don't want fine grained error control.

A for comprehension will "short-circuit" itself on the first error found, and this is almost always what you want.

The bad thing you are doing is using `String` to do flow control of exceptions. You should at all times use `Either[Exception, Whatever]` and fine tune logging with `scala.util.control.NoStackTrace` and `scala.util.NonFatal`.

There are much better alternatives, specifically:

`scalaz.EitherT` and `scalaz.ValidationNel`.

**Update**:(this is incomplete, I don't know exactly what you want). You have better options than matching, such as `getOrElse` and `recover`.

```
def testPerson(person: Person): Person = {
  val attempt = Try {
    val pn = testPersonName(person.name)
    val a = testAddress(person.address)
    testPhone(person.phone)
  }
  attempt match {
    case Success(person) => //..
    case Failure(exception) => //..
  }
}
```

Comment: also `Either[Exception, Whatever]` is basically equivalent of `Try[Watever]`

Comment: @dmitry - For a given definition of "basically"

Comment: @dmitry Not necessarily, you cannot always use `Try` for flow control. There are very specific usage scenarios for the two constructs.

Comment: @dmitry and @flavian So, can I use `Try` instead of `Either` in this example ?

Comment: @flavian I cannot see many cases where you would write `Either[Exception, T]` and do something that you couldn't have done with `Try[T]` instead. What can it be?

Comment: @Michael In your case... no.  As you're using Strings rather than Exceptions

Comment: @dmitry Chaining RPC calls with futures and propagating the error is a simple example.

Comment: @KevinWright I see. Suppose I change `Either[String, ...]` to `Either[Exception, ...]`. Can I replace it with `Try` now ?

Comment: @Michael, yes you can. Wrap the whole block in a `Try` and output whatever exception.

Comment: @Michael You Could make your code a little cleaner, but `Try` still doesn't have anything built-in to help specifically with the aggregation of errors.  It may even by harder as you'd then find yourself with a single `Exception` representing multiple errors.

Comment: @KevinWright I understand that. Using `Try` instead of `Either` and aggregating errors instead of failing fast are two different orthogonal problems.

Comment: @flavian - Using `Try` here doesn't answer the original requirement for aggregation.

Comment: @KevinWright I know, as I said my answer is incomplete. If Michael can tell me what the usage context is(HTTP request to validate etc), I can be helpful.

Comment: I'm (only *slightly*) tempted to downvote this for not actually answering the question or the underlying requirement; but the votes suggest that you're doing *something* right...

Comment: @KevinWright Well, I upvoted your answer as it better fits the question. I'm hoping you don't give in to temptation.:)

Comment: @flavian Can't just write a smiley, it's apparently too short for a comment, so... :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, we can [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap[A1,A2](f:A=%3EEither[A1,A2]):(CC[A1],CC[A2])) a `List` of `Either`s in order to partition elements based on their `Either`'s side.

```
// def testName(pn: Name): Either[String, Name] = ???
// def testAddress(a: Address): Either[String, Address] = ???
// def testPhone(p: Phone): Either[String, Phone] = ???
List(testName(Name("name")), testAddress(Address("address")), testPhone(Phone("phone")))
  .partitionMap(identity) match {
    case (Nil, List(name: Name, address: Address, phone: Phone)) =>
      Right(Person(name, address, phone))
    case (left, _) =>
      Left(left)
  }
// Either[List[String], Person] = Left(List("wrong name", "wrong phone"))
// or
// Either[List[String], Person] = Right(Person(Name("name"), Address("address"), Phone("phone")))
```

If the left side is empty, then no elements were `Left` and thus we can build a `Person` out of the `Right` elements.

Otherwise, we return a `Left` `List` of the `Left` values.

---

Details of the intermediate step (`partitionMap`):

```
List(Left("bad name"), Right(Address("addr")), Left("bad phone"))
  .partitionMap(identity)
// (List[String], List[Any]) = (List("bad name", "bad phone"), List[Any](Address("addr")))
```