# Applicative instance for ZipList in Scala

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

This is a follow-up to [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30985397/ziplist-with-scalaz) of my recent previous questions:

I would like to define a *zip* `Applicative` instance for `List` (and probably `Set` and `Map`). For example:

```
val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val fs: List[Int => Int] = List(f1, f2, f3)
val ys: List[Int] = xs <*> fs // expected to be List(f1(1), f2(2), f3(3))
```

So I defined a `ZipList` and its `Applicative`:

```
case class ZipList[A](val list: List[A])

implicit val zipListApplicative = new Applicative[ZipList] {

  def point[A](a: => A): ZipList[A] = ZipList(List(a))

  def ap[A, B](za: => ZipList[A])(zf: => ZipList[A => B]): ZipList[B] = {
    val bs = (za.list zip zf.list) map {case (a, f) => f(a)}
    ZipList(bs)
  }
}
```

and can use it as follows:

```
 scala> val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
 xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

 scala> val fs: List[Int => Int] = List(_ + 2, _ + 2, _ +1)
 fs: List[Int => Int] = List(<function1>, <function1>, <function1>)

 scala> ZipList(xs) <*> ZipList(fs)
 res4: ZipList[Int] = ZipList(List(3, 4, 4))
```

It seems to be working but maybe I am missing something.

- Does `zipListApplicative` comply to the applicative laws ?
- Is `ZipList` supposed to be a stream because the `point` should generate an infinite stream of values ? Why ?

Comment: "What is wrong with the following definition ?" I don't know. What is wrong with them? What problems are you having?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see the question is not clear. I will try to clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applicatives should satisfy the law

```
point identity <*> v == v
```

which yours does not since

```
point identity List(1,2,3) == List(1)
```

`pure a` for a zip list should return an infinite stream of `a` which is why you need a lazy data structure.

Comment: I see it now, thank you. Could you give an example what can go wrong if my _quasi_-applicative does not satisfy the identity law ?

Comment: @Michael For example, `ZipList(List(1, 2, 3)).map(_ + 1)` will return `ZipList(List(2))` instead of `ZipList(List(2, 3, 4))`